# recommendation, store file in memory and send it by email

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am generating a report in excel from a query to a database, I would like to generate that report, store it in memory (not save anywhere physical) and take it from memory to send by email, is there any way to do that? Thanks for your directions, I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

XSSFWorkbook object maintain the in memory excel data. then you can use output stream to send data. As you are talking about email. You might need to change this stream to DataSource and DataHandler.
This link might help
https://hobione.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/hssfworkbook-object-write-it-to-excel-send-it-as-an-attachment/